# Select button in a grid view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  autogenerateselectbutton="True" selectedindex="0" 
autogeneratecolumns="True" allowpaging="true" runat="server" CssClass="style39" 
datakeynames="Email" RowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" ShowSelectButton="True">>
```

I have this select button in my grid view. I have a delete button in the page. I want to delete the selected row but how can I pass the value to the delete function so that the I can write a code to delete the selected row in the database. I want to know which row is selected how to pass the value.

My grid view has a column called email and user name. I want to pass the selected row email. Thanks

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "CommandName")
        {
            String Email = e.CommandArgument.ToString(); // will Return current Row primary key value

            MySqlConnection connectionString = new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=surelyknown;Uid=root");
            connectionString.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();


            command = new MySqlCommand("DELETE from tbl_group, tbl_usergroups using tbl_group inner join tbl_usergroups where tbl_group.GroupID =@Email And tbl_usergroups.tbl_group_GroupID =@Email", connectionString);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Email", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
            command.Parameters["@Email"].Value = Email;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `RowCommand` event of Gridview

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "CommandName")
    {
      String Email = e.CommandArgument.ToString(); // will Return current Row primary key value
      //..Put deletion code here....

      //.....
     }
 }
```

Comment: In the page load, you are binding the data again, it should be like... if(!IspostBack) {Bind data gridview here..}

Answer (score 0):

- If you are not going to delete multiple rows at the same time on the gridview a separate delete button is not needed
- You can simply place the delete button inside a template field in your gridview. That way, you won't need to select a gridview row then press the delete button on your page(2 steps)
- You can then write a click event for that button & fetch the current gridview row's current index by either using **DataKeys** or **e.CommandArgument**

Let me know if you need any more help with this.